# Tentando testar um endpoint de API e obtive este erro de rede 500? Poderia ser o corpo ou o proxy?

Tags: isapi

POST http://localhost:8080/create-customer
500
226 ms
Network
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: cf5d5989-5a93-41af-8d05-e1f7539de8d5
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 137
Request Body
Response Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 18 Feb 2022 00:50:23 GMT
Connection: close
Response Body

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Server Fault is an English language community. Please translate your question into English.

Comment: Trying to test an API endpoint and got this 500 network error? Could it be the body or the proxy?

Comment: Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1094038/edit) your question appropriately.